# How do I navigate to page no 250?

Tags: feature-request, navigation

If I were to explore the questions in a tab whose result set returns 1000+ questions, how do I get to Page 250 without traversing the set 5 pages at a time?

I strongly feel that many questions become "buried" and untouched just because they are in the middle. If you chart it, chances are pages 1323 and a few pages back get explored more often than any of those lying in middle space "limbo".

[image]

**My point: there should a Go to Page: ______.** at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Have you tried editing the URL?

Comment: Click on page 2. Look at the URL. Where it says `page=2`, change to `page=250`. Press Enter. Presto!

Comment: I would argue to use the filters (or focus on ways to improve the filters). That said, I'm not opposed to the idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set page number from the URL. Set `page` argument here like this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?page=250&sort=newest&pagesize=50
                                               ^^^^^^^^
```

So you can directly redirect to page no XXX

e.g. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?page=250&sort=newest&pagesize=50

Comment: Oh yeah, good point.

Comment: Is it still a good point when you consider the variety of StackExchange websites not devoted to programmer communities - communities of people who won't find editing the URL in this way intuitive?

Comment: Anyway, I suppose it wouldn't hurt to add the function to the screen, rather than having to edit the URL manually every time. But it's a good work around, as it addresses my concern. :)

Comment: Agree Richard. While it may suffice for SO, it wouldn't for StackExchange as a whole. :)