# Add a "go to page" when looking through unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, pagination

I am attempting to reduce the number of unanswered questions on one site.

When searching through (unanswered) questions there is a menu at the bottom with pages 1 through 5 and then the last page. For some sites there are many pages (over 1000!)  If you have looked at the questions on (say) the first 13 pages, it is tiresome to have to click 5 and then 7 and so on.

There should be a "go to page" option.

Comment: (as a workaround you can adjust the page number in the url bar)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175439/how-do-i-navigate-to-page-no-250 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172246/adding-a-button-to-improve-navigation-through-the-questions

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  Thanks. That seems pretty much like a duplicate, but I am not expert at the meta of StackExchange at all. If you want to mark it as duplicate, that's fine with me. 

Adjusting the URL does work, but the button seems like a good idea especially for non-programmers.  I have a tiny bit of programming ability, but I bet some sites have users with none at all.

Comment: Well it's bit different, as this one here suggests to type the desired page, not just "next 100" and "prev 100".

Comment: A workaround is to construct the URLs and have a mechanism to open them by some automated means. For instance, I construct [a number series in Geany](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/03/29/using-geany/#numberSeries), do some slight editing to get a list of URLs, and the selected lines with URLs are [opened with Ctrl + 1](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/03/29/using-geany#open-urls), with a 3 seconds delay between each to not upset anything (needs configuration to work).